# Cocoa contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: method failing with error for certain users - Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
// Get into the data folder of it
keychainPath = [keychainPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data/default"];

DLog(@"Keychain data path: %@", keychainPath);

// Define Filemanager
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Catch any errors
NSError *dataError = nil;

// get all the files in the directory
NSArray *dataFiles = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:keychainPath error:&dataError];

if(!dataFiles)
 NSLog(@"Error: %@",dataError);
```

Now this works perfectly fine for most people, but a few have reported problems, with the 'dataError' object giving:

```
  Error: Error
Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 UserInfo=0x14d1fa10 "The folder
“default” doesn’t exist." Underlying Error=(Error
Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be
completed. (OSStatus error -43.)" (File not found))
```

The people having this problem have said that the file / folder 'default' DOES exist exactly where is should be, so I have no idea why this isn't working.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So, what's the value of `keychainPath`? Is `keychainPath` an instance variable or a local variable? Can this code run twice for the same instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Peter, the keychainPath was just some string like '~/Library/etc.etc.'

To answer my own question:

It turns out the problem was because some people's Mac OS X installations were getting confused about the tilde (~)

Using the method

```
[keychainPath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
```

Once this was done, the problem was solved.

I guess the reason for the problem was for people with multiple user accounts, which I didn't have.